# How to create export to excel functionality using umbraco 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco7 CMS . I want to export my specific Document type children. 
I am trying GridView to export. Here is my code (`EMs` is my list -  `List<ExportModel> EMs = products;`)

```
 var grid = new GridView();
 grid.DataSource = EMs;
 grid.DataBind();

 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Contact.xls");
 Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

 Response.Charset = "";
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

 grid.RenderControl(htw);

 Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
```

Every time I get a blank file. Please help me out ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you sure EMs is not null or empty? Have you tried just rendering the GridView before adding the Excel stuff (to make sure it isn't actually empty)?

Comment: Yes, My EMs has records but it wont binding to grid. is any possible cause for this ? is any alternative to this ? If yes, Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use something like EPPlus to generate the XLS spreadsheet. It allows full control of the spreadsheet generation and allows you to do things like set up individual worksheets etc.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/documentation